# Arduino, RS232 and SIM800L EVB 2.0 (not responding on AT command)

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I buy a SIM800L EVB 2.0 modul for Arduino (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/SIM800L-V2-0-5V-Wireless-GSM-GPRS-MODULE-Quad-Band-W-Antenna-Cable-Cap/32465337183.html).

First I tested modul with all pins connect to Arduino. Modul successfully response on AT commands (but not register on network).

Next day is the same. So I connect modul +5V and GND to external power supply with 1000uF capacitor (as in comments on Aliexpress). Modul successfully connected to the network - my GSM number was accessible) (additional GND pin on modul I connect to Arduino GND on digital GND pin).

But modul is not longer respoding on AT command.

So I tested with USB - serial cable (pin 2 and 3 with GND 5) - modul register on network, but not response on AT command (tested via Putty with different baud speed) - no answer.

What else can I try? How to tested if Rx and Tx on modul works or how to know if I accident burned pins on modul or Arduino or USB-serial cable.

Thanks for every reply.

Comment: RS232 is where here? in setup with external power supply, did you connect the ground between Arduino and the module?

Comment: My mistake -  I thought serial cable for PC (USB). Yes I connect GND modul with Arduino and with power supply.

Comment: USB is different then RS232 and both are different from TTL-Serial on Arduino and module. you should not wire USB to TTL-Serial

Comment: Ok tnx for explanation. I add additional test with Arduino and SIM800L.
Digital PIN 10 and 11 is fine - I try with other modul and it's working. So how to test Rx and Tx pins on SIM modul. I measured pin with voltmeter - one is 5V, other is 2.5V. Normal?

Comment: We've solved the problem (my firends) - one of the transistor on the modul was broken. Now works fine.

Comment: I burned out 2 of mine just few minutes ago after connecting to my ESP8266 NodeMCU's UART0, not sure about why, it is really weird. My ESP 8266 have a 3.3V UART0, no way to burn this 5V module out